# Replacing Icon insted of string in active column

Tags: jquery

i am new in jquery and  am generating dynamic html using following json object.
My Html:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Client Name</td>
            <td>ACtive</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="ClientTbody">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    generateHTML();
});

function generateHTML(){
    if (data != null && data.Message == "Success") {
            if (data.Payload.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.Payload, function (i, item) {
                    var tr = '<tr class="edit" title="Edit">';
                    tr += '<td>' + item.clientName + '</td>';                   
                    tr += '<td>' + item.isActive + '</td>';
                    tr += '</tr>';
                    $("#TeamsTbody").append(tr);
                });
            }
        } else {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
}
```

Now my problem is i want **Icon or Image** of r**ight sign or wrong sign** instend of true or false in **active column**.

Comment: why dont you simply checks the condition and append elements like that?

Comment: @Annoop Joshi please give answer what element is append and where to append?

Comment: @AnkitKathiriya kem 6e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    generateHTML();
});

function generateHTML() {
    if (data != null && data.Message == "Success") {
        if (data.Payload.length > 0) {
            $.each(data.Payload, function (i, item) {
                var tr = '<tr class="edit" title="Edit">';
                tr += '<td>' + item.clientName + '</td>';
                 //simplest way is
                tr += '<td>' + (item.isActive ? '<img src="green.png">' : '<img src="red.png">') + '</td>';
                tr += '</tr>';
                $("#TeamsTbody").append(tr);
            });
        }
    } else {
    alert(data.Message);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
tr += '<td>' + item.isActive ? '<img src="active.png">' : '<img src="inactive.png">' + '</td>';
```

Or if you have these two `images`:

```
<img src="true.png">
<img src="false.png">
```

then you can do this:

```
 tr += '<td>' + '<img src="'+item.isActive+'.png">' + '</td>';
```

Answer (score 1):

try this : Create image string as per active status and append it in td. See below script.

**NOTE** - I have put right.png and wrong.png image just for understanding purpose, please update the src with actual image paths.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    generateHTML();
});

function generateHTML(){
    if (data != null && data.Message == "Success") {
            if (data.Payload.length > 0) {
                $.each(data.Payload, function (i, item) {
                   var image = "";
                   if(item.isActive)
                     image = "<img class='right' src='right.png'>";
                   else
                     image = "<img class='wrong' src='wrong.png'>";

                    var tr = '<tr class="edit" title="Edit">';
                    tr += '<td>' + item.clientName + '</td>';                   
                    tr += '<td>' + image  + '</td>';
                    tr += '</tr>';
                    $("#TeamsTbody").append(tr);
                });
            }
        } else {
            alert(data.Message);
        }
}
```